# MVP+Retrofit2+Dagger2 - best way for pass Retrofit apiService to Repository

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2, android-mvp

I use `MPV`+`Dagger2`+`Retrofit2`

I create retrofit `serviseApi`

```
public interface MailService {
    @POST("sendEmail")
    Observable<Boolean> sendMail(@Body MailRequest mail);
}
```

After that I create `Retrofit2` instanse(I have options - change baseUrl, timeOut value and etc in settings, so I can not create Retrofit like Singleton)

```
public class RestApiFactoryImpl implements RestApiFactory{

    private Retrofit retrofit;
    private Utils utils;

    public RestApiFactoryImpl(Utils utils) {
        this.utils = utils;
        this.retrofit = createRetrofit(providesOkHttpClient(loggingInterceptor()));
    }

    private HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(message -> Log.e("loggingInterceptor", message));
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        return interceptor;
    }

    private OkHttpClient providesOkHttpClient(HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor) {
        User user = utils.getSettings();
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(Long.valueOf(user.getTimeOut()), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(Long.valueOf(user.getTimeOut()), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(Long.valueOf(user.getTimeOut()), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
                .build();
    }

    private Retrofit createRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        User user = utils.getSettings();
        String host = user.getHost();
        if (!host.endsWith("/")) host += "/";
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(host)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient).build();
    }


    private Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = createRetrofit(providesOkHttpClient(loggingInterceptor()));
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

    public void clearRetrofit() {
        retrofit = null;
    }

    @Override
    public MailService getMailService() {
        return getRetrofit().create(MailService.class);
    }
}
```

Wheb I update settings - I recreate Retrofit instanse with new settings. And I create module:

```
@Module
class NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    RestApiFactory providesRestApiFactory(Utils utils) {
        return new RestApiFactoryImpl(utils);
    }
}
```

Now I want use it in my Repository. I create new `repository` and pass `RestApiFactory`

```
@Singleton
@Provides
MyRepository provideMyRepository(RestApiFactory restApiFactory) {
    return new MyRepositoryImpl(restApiFactory);
}
```

and use `Retrofit` `apiServices` inside `MyRepositoryImpl` like this:

```
public class MyRepositoryImpl implements MyRepository {

    private RestApiFactory restApiFactory;

    @Inject
    public MyRepositoryImpl(RestApiFactory restApiFactory) {
        this.restApiFactory = restApiFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Boolean> sendEmail(MailRequest mailRequest) {
        return restApiFactory.getMailService().sendMail(mailRequest);
    }
}
```

But I want another way. I wan pas not `RestApiFactory`  and `MailService` for example:

```
    @Provides
    MailService providesRestApiFactory(RestApiFactory restApiFactory) {
        return restApiFactory.getMailService();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    MyRepository provideMyRepository(MailService mailService) {
        return new MyRepositoryImpl(mailService);
    }

public class MyRepositoryImpl implements MyRepository {

        private MailService ailService;

        @Inject
        public MyRepositoryImpl(MailService mailService) {
            this.mailService= mailService;
        }

        @Override
        public Observable<Boolean> sendEmail(MailRequest mailRequest) {
            return mailService.sendMail(mailRequest);
        }
    }
```

But `MyRepository`  is singleton and call `providesRestApiFactory` method once. And if I change settings it not updates.

Comment: why dont you have the providers inside the module?

Comment: In your network module you are creating the restapifactory instance as singleton. It does not matter that you recreate retrofit hence it will never update

Comment: You've asked quite a lot of Dagger 2 questions lately but you haven't accepted or up-voted answers that help you. Please consider giving back to the community by up-voting/accepting answers that were useful and downvoting answers that weren't useful